# How to achieve Recycle Bin functionality in WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I have an application where I'm performing Directory Synchronization between Local and Remote directories using WinSCP .NET assembly.

Now I want to keep overwritten remote files in the Remote recycle bin path e.g. `/tmp/trash`

I read the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_recycle_bin) for achieving the functionality, and I successfully tested it using the WinSCP GUI application.

Now I need to automate the same functionality through WinSCP .NET assembly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings) to set [`DeleteToRecycleBin`, `OverwrittenToRecycleBin` and `RecycleBinPath` settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings#deletetorecyclebin):

```
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("DeleteToRecycleBin", "1"); // or "on"
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("OverwrittenToRecycleBin", "1"); // or "on"
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("RecycleBinPath", "/tmp");
```

---

WinSCP GUI can [generate such code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.